# Django form. How hide colon from initial_text?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying do this:

```
class NoClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    initial_text = ''
    input_text = ''

class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label="TITLE",  required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'name'}),  label_suffix="")
    image = forms.ImageField(label='NEW FILE',widget=NoClearableFileInput,  label_suffix="")

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('title','image')
```

There in class NoClearableFileInput cleaned value initial_text.
In fields 'title' and 'image' use label_suffix, but from initial_text symbol ":" remained.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdxmq.png)

How get rid of the colons?

Answer (score 19):

This just worked for me with Django 2.2:

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label_suffix = ""  # Removes : as label suffix

    # ...the rest of the form code...
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to override the `label_suffix` on initialization. Try making the following changes:

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(ImageUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # ... (the rest of your code) ...
```

Comment: This doesn't helping. Colon form initial_text not hide.

Answer (score 0):

There is `label_suffix=":"` parameter to form's `__init__` method - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.label_suffix
So, to remove trailing colon from label, you can pass `label_suffix=""` when initializing form in the view, for example:

```
class SomeView(FormView):
...
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["label_suffix"] = ""
        return kwargs
```

Or, you can override this parameter in form's `__init__` method:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["label_suffix"] = ""
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem (extra colon in the end of an input label). The solution I used is to have label = '' when defining form fields and directly write the label in html followed by inserting the form field.