# Django customize Label of form

Tags: python, django

whenever I add a Labels to ModelForm, the Label will look in the HTML like this:

```
                      #v check this colon
<label for="id_url">URL:</label>
```

When I created the labels like this:

```
class FieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Field

        fields = (
            'title',
            'url',
        )

        labels = {
            'title': 'Title',
            'url': 'URL'
```

Where do the colons at the end of the Label in the HTML come from and how to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but found answer here: [Django form. How hide colon from initial_text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602903/django-form-how-hide-colon-from-initial-text)

```
class FieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label_suffix = ""  # Removes : as label suffix
```

Comment: So label_suffix is what it's called. I could have found that myself, never mind. Thanks!